# Android Custome listview with checkbox selection

Tags: android, checkbox

i need to save the checkbox selected items to an arraystring and also need to put select all common checkbox

here is my custome adapter class code.
 http://%20drive.google.com/open?id=0ByOHXkk-NSz0MnRaX1M3UE9HX2M%20%E2%80%93

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link was not working ,but i suggest that you can bind your string , corresponding check box, selection state in view holder
And on selection event you can store that string and selection state.
For select all you can maintain a boolean and on selection you can reload the list with updated adapter.